# Is there any way to save Map<String,TupleValue> to Cassandra using Spring Data?

Tags: java, cassandra, tuples, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to save data to Cassandra using Spring Data and I am not able to save Map with String as key and value as TupleValue. Is using Tuple inside Map is possible in Spring Data?

Im using  Cassandra 3.11.3.5112 | DSE 5.1.12 and Spring-data-cassandra 2.1.5.

```
@Column("meters")
    @FrozenValue
    @CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.MAP, typeArguments= {DataType.Name.TEXT, DataType.Name.TUPLE})
    private Map<String,TupleValue> meters;
```

I also tried using @tuple with class

```
@Tuple
@Data
public class MeterTuple {

    @Element(0)
    String first;

    @Element(1)
    String second;
}
```

```
@Column("meters")
    @FrozenValue
    private Map<String,MeterTuple> meters;
```

For the TupleValue I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 1
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:239) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:230) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:225) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:281) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.java:85) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.map(DataType.java:462) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.map(DataType.java:475) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getDataTypeFor(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:224) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.findDataType(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:187) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getDataType(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:170) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory(CassandraMappingContext.java:584) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataType(CassandraMappingContext.java:547) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getPropertyTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:725) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.lambda$getTargetType$3(MappingCassandraConverter.java:709) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:706) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:747) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeMapFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:402) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:379) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.QueryUtils.createInsertQuery(QueryUtils.java:101) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:554) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:547) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:80) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ge.cassandra.serviceImpl.MeasurementImplATA.saveMeasurementsAta(MeasurementImplATA.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ge.tca.RealConsumer.consume(RealConsumer.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1224) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1217) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

If I use @Tuple I'm getting the below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter cqlType cannot be null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:228) ~[guava-19.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.lookupCodec(CodecRegistry.java:561) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:495) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getPropertyTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:731) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.lambda$getTargetType$3(MappingCassandraConverter.java:718) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:706) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:747) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeMapFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:402) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:379) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.QueryUtils.createInsertQuery(QueryUtils.java:101) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:554) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:547) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:80) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ge.cassandra.serviceImpl.MeasurementImplATA.saveMeasurementsAta(MeasurementImplATA.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ge.tca.RealConsumer.consume(RealConsumer.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1224) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1217) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) [spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Care to file a bug report at https://jira.spring.io?

Comment: Thanks. I have created one https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-651